# Create VM Using Libvirt & KVM

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, kvm, libvirt, vmware-workstation

I am trying to create a virtual machine using libvirt and KVM on Ubuntu (installed in VM workstation ). My goal is to programmatically create, start, stop, and delete virtual machines using Python and the libvirt library.

Here's my code:

```py
import libvirt

def create_vm(name, memory):
    conn = libvirt.open()
    if conn is None:
        print('Failed to connect to the hypervisor')
        return

    try:
        # Check if the virtual machine already exists
        if conn.lookupByName(name):
            print(f'Virtual machine {name} already exists')
            return

        # Create the virtual machine
        xmlconfig = f'''
            <domain type='kvm'>
                <name>{name}</name>
                <memory unit='KiB'>{memory}</memory>
                <vcpu placement='static'>1</vcpu>
                <os>
                    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-2.12'>hvm</type>
                    <boot dev='hd'/>
                </os>
                <devices>
                    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
                        <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
                        <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/disk_image.qcow2'/>
                        <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
                        <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
                    </disk>
                    <interface type='network'>
                        <mac address='52:54:00:aa:bb:cc'/>
                        <source network='default'/>
                        <model type='virtio'/>
                        <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
                    </interface>
                </devices>
            </domain>
        '''

        conn.createXML(xmlconfig, 0)
        print(f'Virtual machine {name} created successfully')

    except libvirt.libvirtError as e:
        print(f'Failed to create virtual machine: {str(e)}')

    conn.close()

# Usage example
create_vm('my_vm', 1024)
```

However, when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
libvirt: QEMU Driver error: Domain not found: no domain with matching name 'my_vm'
Failed to create virtual machine: Domain not found: no domain with matching name 'my_vm'
```

I have already installed and configured libvirt and verified that virtualization is enabled on my physical machine.

Can someone please help me understand what could be causing this error and how I can successfully create the virtual machine using libvirt and KVM?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You're checking the return value of `lookupByName` to detect missing VM, but this method raises an exception when the VM requested doesn't exist. So you need a `try/except` block instead.